# Checking if the site resolve a DNS or not

Tags: php5, networking

I've written code to check whether a domain resolves DNS or not like follows. It is working fine, but I doubt whether there is a simple way to check this by using `[dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)'

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$get = get_headers($url); //Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response to a HTTP request
if (preg_match('/^HTTP\/\d\.\d\s+(200|301|302)/', $get[0])){
$parse = parse_url($url); //Parse a URL and return its components
$ip = gethostbyname($parse['host']);  // Get the IPv4 address corresponding to a given Internet host name 
//ip2long — Converts a string containing an (IPv4) Internet Protocol dotted address into a proper address
return (ip2long($ip) == true) ? true : false;
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing way more than necessary, if all you want to verify is that the hostname resolves to an IP address.

[`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/gethostbyname) comes pretty close to doing the job:

> Returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified `hostname` on failure.

Actually, that's annoying.  Try [`gethostbynamel()`](http://php.net/gethostbynamel) instead:

> Returns an array of IPv4 addresses or `FALSE` if `hostname` could not be resolved.

So, you could just do

```
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
return gethostbynamel($url_parts['host']) ? true : false;
```

---

Note, however, that the `gethostbyname()` family of functions relies on the operating system to do the name resolution in whatever way it is configured.  Usually, that means using DNS.  However, it might also use a local `hosts` file, NIS, LDAP, Multicast DNS, etc.  `dns_get_record()` would actually perform a DNS lookup, independent of the machine's preferred name resolution mechanism.  If you want to go that route, then it looks like [`checkdnsrr($host, 'A')`](http://php.net/checkdnsrr) would be convenient.

The distinction is almost always inconsequential, but I thought I'd mention it since you specifically mentioned DNS resolution in your question.